# Why does functional component render twice?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I got a component that fetches data from a GraphQL route using Apollo.

When I load the page, it console logs the data twice.

This is the component :

```
const LAUNCHES_QUERY = gql`
  query LaunchesQuery {
    launches {
      flight_number
      mission_name
      launch_date_local
      launch_success
    }
  }
`

const Launches = () => {

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LAUNCHES_QUERY)

    const getLaunches = () => {

        if (loading) return <div>Loading..</div>
        if (error) console.log(error)
        console.log(data)
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='display-4 my-3'>Launches</h1>
      {getLaunches()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's the initial render, and a render after after the data comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useQuery` is an async operation, the first render will be while fetching the data and next render will be when data is fetched. Therefore, it is logging the twice.

Comment: But in both logs the data is fully resolved. Shouldn't the log be empty/undefined in the first render, while it's still fetching?

Comment: if you look at the loading state, it will true and then it will be false. Please check that.

Comment: Now I see. So I shouldn't be worried of performance issues with this practice?

Comment: yes, no need to be concerned about the performance here,  this is a normal behaviour.

Comment: Thank u. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One is from start of the `useQuery`, and another one is from once `useQuery` is done fetching.

You can console.log `loading` to see.